# mysql (5.1) > create table with name from a variable

Tags: mysql, variables, dynamic, tablename

I'm trying to create a table with a name based on the current year and month(`2011-09`), but MySQL doesn't seem to like this.

```
SET @yyyy_mm=Year(NOW())+'-'+Month(NOW());
CREATE TABLE `survey`.`@yyyy_mm` LIKE `survey`.`interim`;
SHOW TABLES IN `survey`;

+-----------+
| interim   |
+-----------+
| @yyyy_mm  |
+-----------+
```

If I do `CREATE TABLE;` without the ticks around `@yyyy_mm`, I get a generic syntax error.

`@yyyy_mm` resolves to `2020`.

Comment: Identifiers are not variables. Variables are not identifiers. This requires the use of "dynamic SQL" -- it's icky in all databases I've worked with.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929244/mysql-create-table-with-dynamic-database-name and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530755/mysql-variables-storing-database-name

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SET @yyyy_mm=DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m');
SET @c = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `survey`.`',@yyyy_mm, '` LIKE `survey`.`interim`');
PREPARE stmt from @c;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
set @yyyy_mm=concat(year(now()),'-',month(now()));
set @str = concat('create table survery.`', @yyyy_mm,'` like survey.interim;');
prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```